# Redirection rule in apache with subDomain?

Tags: apache, apache-config

greetings all, 
i have multi sub-domain on my domainname.com , i need to redirect www.*.domainname.com to 
*.domainname.com

ex:
http://www.sub1.domainname.com
to
http://sub1.domainname.com

any ideas how to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and see does this help

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.sub1.domainname.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://sub1.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or try this for dynamic subdomain

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.(.*).domainname.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://%1.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: my problem is that the subDomains are dynamic not static, so this rule won't help my, any other ideas ?